# Tcl regsub used with subst produces unexpected result

Tags: regex, tcl

Edit: 
I was trying to replace "xor_in0" with "xor_in[0]" and "xor_in1" with "xor_in[1]" for a given str parameter. Here "xor_in0", "xor_in1" is parameter passed in and I represent it as "key", and "xor_in[0]", "xor_in[1]" is the value parameter stored in an array. Notice the point here is to replace every "key" in "str" with "value" . Here is my testing code:

```
set str "(xor_in0^xor_in1)"
set str1 "xor_in0^xor_in1" # another input
set key "xor_in0"
set value "xor_in\[0\]"
set newstr ""
set nonalpha  "\[^0-9a-zA-Z\]"
regsub -all [subst {^\[(*\]($key)($nonalpha+)}] $str [subst -nobackslashes {$value\2}] newstr
puts $newstr
```

But somehow it doesn't work... I also tried to remove [subst ...] and it still failed to match anything. This is somehow against my knowledge of regular expression. Please help.

Comment: First thing to check: are strings fed into regsub what you actually expect?

Comment: do you mean $str or [subst ...]? $str is correct. But [subst ...] will make things complicated and I doubt there be some issue. But I don't know how to debug it. I need subst to eval the parameter passed into function.

Comment: I think the problem lies in [subst] and {} used together. If I don't use {}, instead, use "", it worked part: regsub -all "[subst $key]" $str [subst {$value}] newstr. But this is not what I wanted... I need to match the "^" sign and () to keep the remaining...

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems a bit over-complicated to me.

Let's look at the `regsub` that you're actually going to execute. There's a trick to doing that easily; if your command is:

```
regsub -all [subst {^\[(*\]($key)($nonalpha+)}] $str [subst -nobackslashes {$value\2}] newstr
```

Then we can print out what it's going to try to do with:

```
puts [list regsub -all [subst {^\[(*\]($key)($nonalpha+)}] $str [subst -nobackslashes {$value\2}] newstr]
```

That reveals that you're *really* doing this:

```
regsub -all {^[(*](xor_in0)([^0-9a-zA-z]+)} (xor_in0^xor_in1) {xor_in[0]\2} newstr
```

The part that looks a bit strange in there is the `([^0-9a-zA-z]+)` at the end of the RE. It's *legal* but odd as we can write things a bit differently with `\W` for matching a non-alpha:

```
regsub -all {^[(*](xor_in0)(\W+)} $str {xor_in[0]\2} newstr
```

And that seems to work. What might the bug be then? **The definition of `nonalpha`, as you're using `"\[^0-9a-zA-z\]"` instead of `"\[^0-9a-zA-Z\]"`.** Yes, a literal `^` lies in the ASCII (and Unicode) range from `A` to `z`…

---

OTOH, I'd actually expect a transformation to really be done like this:

```
set newstr [regsub -all {(\y[a-zA-Z]+_in)(\d+)} $str {\1[\2]}]
```

The only things you're not used to there are `\y` (a word boundary constraint) and `\d` (match any digit). Or, for a simple transformation (mapping all instances of a literal substring to another literal substring):

```
set newstr [string map [list $key $value] $str]
```

Comment: Thanks. The A-z was a typo :) Your first answer gave  me a good start for generalization. And the last one is really cool. I'm not a Tcl programmer but it changes my mind of regex usage.

Comment: A second thought, the last one seems not a good fit. I can't change "xor_in12" to "xor_in[1]2". Instead, it should be "xor_in[12]". This is why regex is used I guess. I'll see if the first answer is better.

Comment: Your first answer is not working too. If you use "xor_in0" string directly, it possibly works. But the problem here is caused by using "key" parameter and to evaluate within a {} block. So the solution with direct string won't help. I updated the comment a little bit for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the real problem to my question is the A-z typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple is generally better:

```
regsub -all {\d+} $s {[&]} s
```

Takes care of your examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is overly simple :) The passed in key, value, and string to be replaced probably don't contain \d though it's the normal case. But the original syntax will cover most of them if not all.